# What happened at the beginning of the calendar?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

In *The Way of Kings*, the death quotes have years they were recorded in, such as 1171. The Gregorian calendar is based on the birth of Jesus as year one A.D. What event is the calendar on Roshar based on, if any?

<sub>please tag spoilers</sub>

Comment: [The Coppermind](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Roshar#Calendar) is unenlightening on the subject.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JJtJhHwpKdow01n2-bsT3scVvqJd6lZh4uvpNwcslv8/htmlview?fbclid=IwAR0P3gitO8A8iyaWLGnPGVXcDK_VK-JQ4bAAyTjPrRbbmO3h6Rn8COLxc1w# - https://coppermind.net/wiki/Adonalsium#Shattering_of_Adonalsium?

Comment: @Valorum that's a different calendar. The time OP is referring to should be about 10k years after the shattering.

Comment: @OP it seems [we don't know yet](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Era_of_Solitude#Time_Keeping), but looking at some dates it seems to be an event between the Recreance and the Hierocracy.

Comment: @MartinEnder found a reference for that fact: https://wob.coppermind.net/events/3/#e125 struggled to find any others but I've been out of the loop for a while

Answer (score 2):

We do not yet know the occasion that started the common calendar. It's been confirmed that it is none of the major historical events that we know of, and nobody has asked Brandon directly (the [only question (2018-11-17)](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/375/#e12366) was answered "I would need to look it up" and it hasn't been asked again since).

We [do know](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/362/#e11145) that the calendar is a Vorin convention that has been widely adopted, though with different names for days/weeks/months (presuming that's what he means by "different numbering conventions"):

> ### Skype Q&A 2018-10-08:
>
> **Jofwu:**  Is the current year number (1174) just a Vorin convention, or is
>   everyone on Roshar using the same calendar?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson:** It is a Vorin convention, but the Vorin convention
>   has been adopted by a lot of cultures.
>
> **Ravi:** Just like our Gregorian?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson:** Yeah. But there are different numbering conventions.

We [also know](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/3/#e125) that the [False Desolation](https://coppermind.net/wiki/False_Desolation), [the Day of Recreance](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Day_of_Recreance), and the [Hierocracy](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Hierocracy) happened independently of the year date.